# How can I determine the right timezone for daylight saving for a given timezone, given values for date, and time in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dst

In an Angular app using Typescript, I have integer values for day, month, year, hour and minute, (coming from `FormControl` objects) and I know the geographic timezone (e.g. United Kingdom).

I want to derive the actual timestamp (millis) from this.

I am doing

```
let timestampDate = new Date();
```

(I believe this is UTC by default)

Then I am doing

```
timestampDate.setFullYear(this.timestampYear.value ? parseInt(this.timestampYear.value) : 0, this.timestampMonth.value ? parseInt(this.timestampMonth.value) - 1 : 0, this.timestampDay.value ? parseInt(this.timestampDay.value) : 0);
timestampDate.setHours(this.timestampHour.value ? parseInt(this.timestampHour.value) : 0);
timestampDate.setMinutes(this.timestampMinute.value ? parseInt(this.timestampMinute.value) : 0);
```

How can I use the system to determine whether the given time is GMT or BST, given the date value?

And, once determined, I believe I cannot set the Timezone on the Typescript `Date` object, but I could then at least offset the hour value accordingly.

I am getting the timestamp value with

```
var timestamp = timestampDate.valueOf();
```

*Update*: if this is not possible/easy in Typescript without implementing DST calculation rules myself, should I just do it in my back-end using Java?

Comment: Are the values in the user's local time zone? Or some given time zone?  You seem to be mixing the two in your question.  If it's some given time zone, how is it provided?  Or are you wanting to hard-code it to UK time regardless of the user's time zone?

Comment: You may also want to read up on the `Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: And no - you should not implement DST calculation rules yourself.  Ever.

Comment: Also, why is it that you think you would need to adjust the input for DST at all? Isn't the time given *already* in terms of the desired time zone?